# How is failover handled in case of database sharding?

Tags: database, sharding

I have been trying to understand how database sharing works.
Let’s say I have a database with two separate shards, one for customers whose last names begin with letters A through M and another for those whose names begin with the letters N through Z.
If the first shared handling customer A through M goes down for some reason, how is the failover handled?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know that there's "an" answer to this, but "hinted handoff" is something that (at least) Cassandra does that at least partially addresses this problem. Also, a database big enough to be sharded may also be replicated, so you could read/write from another replica while the other is down, of course at some performance cost.

Comment: Perhaps better asked on sibling site: https://dba.stackexchange.com